# Prevent music volume from being lowered when using turn-by-turn navigation

Tags: audio, google-maps, music-player, volume

I use a Nexus 6 on Lollipop.  Sometimes I'll try to listen to music over Bluetooth while using Google Maps turn-by-turn navigation in my car.  The volume on the music is reduced whenever Google Maps gives the next turn, which is irritating.  I changed the settings in Google Maps to output using the device's speaker, but it still lowers the media volume over Bluetooth to give me turn information.

Is there any way -- ideally without needing root privileges -- to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I guess that's the reason Google Maps do it, to make sure that you can hear the next turn (and prevent users from blaming Google if they miss it). Anyway, your question is on-topic.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, I imagine that's the case, but I am both aware of and accepting of the risk that I might not hear the directions.  In any case, the pausing doesn't really work because the delay in Bluetooth means my music doesn't get lowered until after it's already given the directions.

Comment: This is 2021, I just bought a Nissan Kicks and the same issue happens, both on Apple Play and Android Auto, when I'm using the Sirious XM or FM radio along with the directions. I couldn't figure out a way to stop the volume reduction, just wondering if anybody has found a way? It's hard to believe it's still not an optional feature

Comment: @cleberz I never found anything better than muting the directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure at what point it was added, but it is now possible to mute turn-by-turn navigation.  This is not exactly ideal (I'd prefer to have the directions come out of the phone speaker and not pause Bluetooth), but it will do the job.  [Google provides instructions here](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3273406?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en):

> You can silence voice navigation by touching the mute button.
>
> 1. Open the Google Maps app maps.  [image: Maps logo]
> 2. Start navigation.
> 3. In the top right, touch Sound. [image: Sound]
> 4. Touch Mute. [image: Mute]
>
> To turn voice navigation back on, touch
> Mute > Sound.
>
> Tip: You can also silence voice navigation by touching the volume
> controls on your device.

Answer (score 5):

From what I've read elsewhere, this functionality is generally handled by the application playing the music/audio. So, I've been testing out various players, and found a couple that does what the question is requesting, MX Player and Poweramp.

MX Player is primarily known as a video player, but it can also handle a number of audio formats (including Opus, which I happened to be looking for).

One drawback with MX Player is that it can't create dynamic playlists, so you have to have the songs ordered in folders to play in succession.

The other one that does what the question is requesting is the music player app Poweramp, which lets you choose in its settings, under Audio->Audio Focus->Short Audio Focus Change, between no ducking (unchecked), and pausing (checked). Poweramp isn't free, though.

Another app, Rocket Player, is a music player that will let you choose *between* ducking and pausing, but will not allow you to disable it completely, which is what the question is looking for. (The setting is under Settings -> Sound -> Audio Focus -> Temp Focus Action)

For myself, I've found that, especially for audiobooks and podcasts, I actually prefer pausing to ducking or no ducking, so I like Poweramp or Rocket Player for this purpose.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate since the services I have are tied to particular apps but I guess that is the answer.

Comment: Rocket Player does give the option to IGNORE all other apps now. Just tested it: maps, camera shutter sound - make sounds but no longer "duck" (more like stutter!) my music, listening via 3.5mm rn but should be same for BT.

Answer (score 1):

For Samsung devices, I found a solution to this issue by using an app called [SoundAssistant](https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.android.soundassistant?langCd=en). It has a "dual app sound" setting, if you turn it on and choose an app for dual sound (in my case it is Amazon Music), Google Maps will not mute the music.

Answer (score 1):

On Samsung phones, there is a well-known app called [Good Lock](https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.android.goodlock?langCd=en) that can do the trick:

- Within the app, install "SoundAssistant";
- Go to the "Multi sound" option and select "Maps".

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings on your Android phone and search for "sound assistance". Then click on the toggle button to select "multiple audio sources". It works perfectly for Redmi Note 11S and some Samsung phones. Note, the feature may not be available for your Android device depending on the generation and/or software.