# Stop notifications from briefly lowering media volume

Tags: notifications, volume-control, media-player, lg-g6

I have an LG G6 running Oreo and whenever media is playing and a notification sound comes through something briefly lowers (not fully muted) my media volume. How can I stop this? I don't want notification sounds to change my media volume.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I first thought that the OP was asking about modifying the behavior of the sources of the notifications which can be done in with finer levels than before using Notification Categories in Android 8.0 Oreo.

However via the comments, it appears that the OP wants to stop **Audio Ducking** 
from happening in the media player. Unfortunately this is a feature of the 
media app playing the music itself and requires the developer of the app to configure. See 
similar question: [Prevent music volume from being lowered when using turn-by-turn navigation](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/124876/3573)

**Original Answer**

In Android 8.0 Oreo the App can now have Notification Categories

Check the notification setting screen in:

**Settings->Apps & Notification->[App Name]->App Notifications**

[image: Clock App App Notifications Screen]

For the App(s) that are interrupting see if you can either disable sound or adjust the priority to one which suits your needs.

Comment: That seems like only a stopgap measure. What about in cases like receiving texts? I need to be able to receive those sound notifications BUT I don't want them to effect the volume of my music.

Comment: You are referring to Audio Ducking. The app that is playing music handles the ducking. See: [Prevent music volume from being lowered when using turn-by-turn navigation](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/124876/3573)

Comment: Make thst comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Rocket Player, is a music player that will let you choose between ducking and pausing, and will allow you to disable it completely, (The setting is under Settings->Sound->Audio Focus->Temp Focus Action)".

It does give the option to IGNORE all other apps. Just tested it: maps, camera shutter sound, notifications - all make sounds but no longer "duck" (more like stutter!) my music, listening via 3.5mm right now but should be same for BT.

Answer (score 1):

To automate the *Do Not Disturb* toggle, you can use Tasker (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en).

1. Create a **task** that sets *Do Not Disturb* to "No Interruptions"
2. Create a **task** that sets *Do Not Disburb" to "Allow All"
3. Create a **profile**

   - Add trigger to the "No Interruptions" task when a specific application is launched (i.e. YouTube Music),
   - link an Exit **task** that triggers "Allow all"

Answer (score 0):

If your device supports the ***Do Not Disturb*** mode, you can use it to achieve this effect system-wide for any music app as far as notifications are concerned. However, turn-by-turn navigation in *Google Maps* may still duck the audio. (I usually change it to *Alerts Only* and check the map visually for directions.)

By default, *Do Not Disturb* will suppress notification alerts completely, stacking the notifications up in the drawer silently. But depending on your phone model and ROM version, you may be able to fine tune the behavior to allow status bar icons and banner notifications.

Whether or not you allow the icons or banners, *Do Not Disturb* will always suppress the notification sounds. This will allow your music to continue playing uninterrupted even when notifications are getting added to the drawer or even popping up at the top of the screen.